# Подскажите почему это так не работает

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Я новичок и должен разобратся в массивах более детально. 
Смотрел на многие варианты, остановился на этом. Скорее всего так и нужно сделать, но чего-то в нем не хватает. Подскажите пожалуйста(

```
      /*Напишите функцию, которая на вход принимает два массива одинаковой длинны 
    + параметр, описывающий собственно их длинну; и модифицирует их таким образом, 
    что в первом массиве в каждой i-той ячейке находится разница этой ячейки и 
    соответствующей i-той ячейки второго массива, 
    а во втором массиве в каждой i-той ячейке находится сумма этой ячейки и 
    соответствующей i-той ячейки первого массива.*/

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream> 

    using namespace std; 

    int main (){
    int x;
    cout << "Please imput the length of the arrays" << endl;
    cin >> x ;

    int arr1 [x] {5,4,3,2};
    int arr2 [x] {2,3,4,5};

    for (int i = 0; i<=x; i++) 
    {
    arr1 [i] - arr2 [i];
    arr2 [i] + arr1 [i];
    }
    cout << "Result is " << arr1 << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто вы напрочь игнорируете здравый смысл и правила C++.

```
int arr1 [x] {5,4,3,2};
int arr2 [x] {2,3,4,5};
```

В С++ размер массива определяется во время компиляции, а не во время работы. Если уж указываете конкретные значения массива - то просто пишите

```
int arr1[] = {5,4,3,2};
int arr2[] = {2,3,4,5};
```

и получите два массива по 4 элемента.

В массиве из `x` элементов их и в самом деле `x` - от нулевого до `x-1`, так что

```
for (int i = 0; i<=x; i++)
```

тут вы просто выходите за рамки массива.

Значения вы какие-то вычисляете, но *никак их не используете*:

```
arr1 [i] - arr2 [i];
arr2 [i] + arr1 [i];
```

Да и выводите

```
cout << "Result is " << arr1 << endl;
```

просто адрес, где в памяти находится массив...

От вас хотели вот этого:

```
void func(int* a1, int * a2, int sz)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        int a1i = a1[i];
        a1[i] -= a2[i];
        a2[i] += a1i;
    }
}
```

Разберитесь, как работает этот код, ну и подумайте, как его верно вызвать.

Без этого усилия - ваш вопрос тянет на закрытие со стандартной формулировкой

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.

Поэтому я оставляю вам часть решения для самостоятельной работы...

Comment: сейчас смотрю инициализацию массивов в шарпе, и нигде не могу найти что именно значит ваше int * a1

что значит этот знак умножения, на последок не подскажите ?

Comment: @AntonioParroni, почитайте про указатели

Comment: Это - указатель на `int`, тип, к которому приводится массив при передаче в функцию.

Comment: @Harry я просто не понимаю зачем это именно так писать. И почему обычное обявление здесь не пригодно. Тем более если здесь в условиях задачи говорят что нужно ввести только длинну массивов.

Comment: Раз массив неизвестен заранее, в функцию его надо передавать или как `int*a`, или как `int a[]` - что одно и то же. Если размер массива указывается во время работы - то массив следует создавать динамически, `int a = new int[x];`. И как вы себе представляете незаполненный массив? (" в условиях задачи говорят что нужно ввести только длину массивов")? Хоть случайными числами тогда заполните...

Comment: @Harry понял, я приблизительно об этом и говорил. Просто я еще мало понял концепцию самых указателей. Сейчас все вправду благодаря вам, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @AntonioParroni, вот такая запись `void func(int a1[], int  a2[], int sz)` является эквивалентом `void func(int* a1, int * a2, int sz)`, но может быть проще для восприятия, более логична, если функция работает именно с массивами.